# selenium web driver - passing variable value from one test case to another

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a variable stateID with value 11 in test case CreateStateID. How do I pass this value to test case DeleteStateID in selenium wedriver?

This works fine in selenium IDE but not in webdriver.

In selenium IDE CreateStateID

```
storeEval  | /\d*$/.exec(storedVars['myLocation'])  | stateID
```

I had to write java code for above statement in my selenium2 program.

In selenium IDE DeleteStateID

```
echo | ${stateID}
```

the selenium2 code for this is

```
System.out.println("${sid}");
```

which prints out null.

Is the best way to write java method where I pass stateID from one test case to another?

Thanks

Comment: probably this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019319/comparing-result-of-one-junit-test-with-another-test-in-same-class/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

- check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019319/comparing-result-of-one-junit-test-with-another-test-in-same-class/) - it could help.
- Another approach would be have the variable as **static** variable inside the tests, with getters and setters:

  ```
  private static String neededVariable;

  public String getVariable(){
    return neededVariable;
  }

  public void setVariable(String var){
    this.neededVariable = var;
  }
  ```

And later in the code:

```
   String stateID = //the way how you get it from the storeEval
   setVariable(stateID);
```

And in another test:

```
   String stateID = getVariable();
   //... and work with the stateID as you need
```

Works ok in mine tests